# Raspberry pi 4 error when importing sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

After installing scikit-learn using `pip install -U scikit-learn`, I get the following

```
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.5)
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-1.1.2
```

But when I tried to import it, without any other code, I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 1
----> 1 import sklearn

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_highs/_highs_wrapper.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_compare_exchange_8
```

I've tried to reinstall it several times but nothing works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined symbol: \_\_atomic\_exchange\_8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084134/undefined-symbol-atomic-exchange-8)

Comment: Nope, that's a different library

Comment: try running python, then import scipy, then scipy.test().  I am sorry that I don't know the answer but it points to scipy being the original problem.  maybe that will help your investigation

Answer (score 1):

a possible answer/workaround is to launch python prefixed with a command to load this library.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python
```

or add this as an environment variable that is set in ~/.bashrc file or other appropriate place.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0
```

and then you can test breaking again with

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

short background:

I have been building up a Python 3.11.0 (very new right now) install on Raspberry pi 3B+ and also on a Raspberry pi 4.

Many libraries need to compile in place and for some I have downloaded the source code and compiled the latest or a specific tag from the repository.

I thought I had scipy installed correctly because it imported ok but when I got to scikit-learn I had the same problem posed in this question.  going back to scipy I found that certain parts of it would crash when importing.  I went back and uninstalled scipy, set this variable and then I installed scipy from the repository, following a guide on their site to install some prerequisites and then the basic installation was as follows

```
cd ~/github
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git scipy
cd scipy
git checkout v1.9.3
git submodule update --init
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python -m pip install .
```

after doing this sklearn loaded correctly even though I did not re-install that.

of course, results may vary.  loading new versions of Python and installing these advanced and complicated libraries can be extremely difficult.

Comment: I could force the same issue with `import scipy.optimize` - hope that gets fixed ...